# How do I find the expected value when K=1 if 0.9|W1|<|W2| and $0$ otherwise?

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value

Suppose that $N=(N_1,N_2)^T$ has a standard Gaussian distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Define $A=(A_1,A_2)$ by

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1.2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1.2 \end{pmatrix}N$$.

Let Y be the random variable such that $K = 1$ if  $0.9|A_1|\lt|A_2|$ and $0$ otherwise.

How can I find the $E(K)$? I know that $E(K) = 1 \cdot (\mathbb{P}(0.9|A_1|<|A2|)$, but how do I find the probability?

Comment: A small hint: Try finding the region defined by $0.9|A_1| < |A_2|$ for fixed $(N_1, N_2) = (x,y)$, in the form of inequalities on $x$ and $y$. The probability of each of the fixed $(x, y)$ can be expressed by the joint density of $N_1$ and $N_2$. (In order to find such regions, I find it helpful to draw each of the sides of the inequality.)

Comment: @HeiniHøgnason Hi, I dont quite follow. Do you mind explaining a bit more?